# Button Command not binding to ViewModel in DatGrid

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, binding, command, mvvm-light

I have ViewModel, Which has a ObservableCollection[Employee] EmpCol , now that ViewModel is bind with my View and and EmpCol is set as with ItemSource of custom control. That custom control generates stackpanels with grids , if there are 4 objects in EmpCol then there will be 4 stackpanels with Grids inside them. Now in those grids, I have a column of Buttons. 
Now my problem is I can't bind Command of that Button in datagrid to RelayCommand in Employee class.

I am using MVVM light toolkit, and I found a way around which actually kind of give full path to binding command like this

```
<Button x:Name="myButton"  Width="20" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" >   
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
 <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click"> 
<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMLocator}, Path=MyVM.Employee.MyButtonCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="False"/>  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Now this above approach works , but in my case I dont have Employee , but collection of Employee, so when I give binding path like this 
                   **Path=MyVM.EmpCol.MyButtonCommand**

It does't work. I have searched a lot , but could't find any solution. 
So any help will be much appreciated to solve my problem.

Thanks,
Maverick

The command binding happens inside a row of a **DataGrid**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tsolution depends on the structure of your view, if you have a master detail view you should create a sub-structure that expects an employee ViewModel as a DataContext and bind that to the currently selected employee. With that you get the correct ViewModel for your view.

If you navigate to a new page the easiest approach might be to to pass the View the id of the employee you want to show and then in code behind call a method on you view model - which you can get from the DataContext propery - to load the correct employee from the database or service.

Alternatively, you can hold the current employee in a application wide acessible variable. E.g. a static variable on your application class, a singleton or static class stored in you resources, or on your ViewLocator (in all cases you may have to provide an empty employee ViewModel when no employee is selected or prevent the opening of the View).

**Edit**:

If a collection of ViewModels is bound to a DataGrid and binding of the command is a problem, this might be a possible solution:

Put the command on a ViewModel that contains the Collection (i.e.the propety that is bound to the ItemsSource of the DataGrid). Then implement the command on this high level ViewModel. You now can use a RelativeSurce binding to access this higher level ViewModel via the DataGrid's parent DataContext property. In your button you can now bind the command and pass the current row's DataContext as the command parameter - the command obviously has to expect this parameter.

**Edit 2**:

Forgot Silverlight does not support all RelativeSource modes, however, it supports binding to a named element, so the following should work ...

Assumptions:

1. The higher level ViewModel is called "EmployeeListViewModel"
2. It has a property called Employees containing the list of EmployeeViewModels
3. The DataContext of the element containing the DataGrid is set to EmployeeListViewModel

Code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding Empoyees}" ...>
    ...
        <Button x:Name="myButton"  Width="20" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" >   
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click"> 
                    <cmd:EventToCommand 
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=dgEmployees, Path=DataContext.MyButtonCommand}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}" 
                        PassEventArgsToCommand="False"/>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Obalix, the problem is with the button binding inside that datagrid. Itemsource of my datagrid is a collection property inside the 'Employee' class and all the events of datagrid are also correctly bind to RelayCommands inside my Employee class . The problem only happens when I goinside datagrid and from there try to bind Relaycomand against button, there it lost its datacontext.

Comment: And it is a known issue of button binding problems inside datagrid and usually the solution is to use static datatcontext , but in my problem Employee class is in a collection , and that collection is a property in my viewmodel, so static datacontext wont work in my case.

Comment: @Maverick: In your original post you did not mention that you were using a DataGrid - you were just talking about "grids". However, I edited the post to contain a solution that might solve your problem.

Comment: yeh I didn't say datagrid , but what I meant was datagrid. I have looked on RelativeSource on web, it seems u can only give two values 'TemplatedParent' or 'self' , but i think ur suggesting to use name of datagrid under which buttons are placed , isn't it ? Can u plz elaborate it little more ?

Comment: @Maverick: Sorry forgot we were talking about Silverlight. But see second edit for a possible solution.

Comment: @Obalix , thanks for the code example. But sorry it doesn't work. As in my case there is one more twist that , that Employee class has a property " PagedCollectionView EmpGridData " which is actually set as ItemSource of datagrid <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dgData" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=mpGridData}" /> And that Employee class has RelayCommand which I am trying to bind with button inside the datagrid... so thats why when I try to get the DataContext of Datagrid , it doesn't hav my RelayCommand !!!

Comment: @Maverick, confused now! What I am trying to say is that you should implement the command not on the item's ViewModel but on a ViewModel that is bound to the data context of an element higher up your XAML hierarchy. This element can be addressed by ElementName and the path has to contain DataContext in order to access the ViewModel and not the element itself. If your current implementation has the command on the item ViewModel, i.e. the ViewModel that is bound to the row you will have to move it somewere else, and use the CommandParameter to get the current item's ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using the Relay command for example

```
public RelayCommand SearchCommand
 {
    get
    {
      return new RelayCommand(GetData);//GetDatais a method for your action on click event
    }
}
```

for Detail you can see at following link

http://codenicely.blogspot.com/2012/01/handling-button-click-event-in.html